# Virtualhost setup on localhost displays indexof

Tags: windows, apache, virtual-hosts

I'm attempting to set up a virtual host on Windows vista32.  I keep getting a listing of the root folder htdocs instead of the site I've setup.

Here's my virtual host entry in Apache httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site-ashback.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.site-ashback.co.uk
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/site-ashback.co.uk"
        DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1               site-ashback.co.uk
```

None of the examples I've been using have shown a few entries which are present in my hosts file thus:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
```

These two lines appear after all the commented examples and I've put my entry after these.  Does this suggest I should use'localhost' instead of 127.0.0.1?

When I click my site in the listing it takes me to the site properly but the address then reads: site-ashback.co.uk/site-ashback.co.uk/.  All I wanted to do is remove the word 'localhost' from local sites addresses when testing so that the path read like the real domain name when we go live.

Comment: Your servername is `site-ashback.co.uk` but you try to connect to `ashback.co.uk`. They're not the same.

Comment: just amended it  - i shortened the examples manually b4 posting  - the problem is still per the amended version

Comment: Did you enable VirtualHosting? The directive is `NameVirtualHost *:80`.

Comment: @ alvits, where do i place this directive please, sorry for my ignorance but i haven't used virtual hosts before. Should i replace the line: <VirtualHost *:80> with <NameVirtualHost*:80>

Comment: ah just noticed that directive is already in the file just above the example blocks ...

Comment: no, nothing? is anybody there .... oh well ...

Comment: This reply may be a little too late. But I just noticed that your entry is `<VirtualHost :80>`. Please try `<VirtualHost *:80>`.